# Force Vue.js to recognize Ajax content as a part of its own app

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, axios

I have a Vue #app that is responsible to pull into a  container external PHP pages loaded via Ajax using Axios.

something like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        pageContent: ''
    },
    methods: {

        runAjax() {

            axios.get('/tmp/page.php').then(response => {

                this.pageContent = response.data;

            }

        });

    },
    mounted() {

        this.runAjax();

    }
});
```

Then the in the HTML

```
<div id="app">

    <div v-html="pageContent" class="ajax-wrapper"></div>

</div>
```

It's ll working great till here, the problem is that the Ajax content loaded in the '.ajax-wrapper'  is not gonna be taken as part of the Vue #app, since its DOM is not immediately loaded on the first page load, but rendered later on by ajax.

As a result, if I define an event click on a  that seats on the content that is loaded by Ajax, something like: Foo ... the directive *v-on:click* will be printed within the markup. That is a sign that the Vue #app doesn't recognize it as its own content.

So, is there a way to tell Vue that when it renders new content, it actually recognize it as a part of its own #app?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know much about Vue, but is it possible to just not start up the Vue instance until after the AJAX content is loaded into the DOM?

Comment: Not sure, but I have several php pages to load inside, so I can't do that in any case. I need the Vue instance to recognize them after any page has been loaded inside

Comment: Sure you could. You could run several AJAX requests for each PHP page that needs to be loaded before calling new Vue(...). I would try that. Otherwise, not sure what you could do if Vue has that limitation.

Comment: The $mount instance method can be used to mount a view instance on a DOM element, but I don't know if that's what you need. I.e. you can mount an instance on the loaded content, assuming you know what it is.

Comment: I tried it already but it keeps not recognizing it. even giving it a timeOut. it's still not interpreted